# Trigger Email on Cloud Page Form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, triggered-send

I changed the logic using single page and only triggering the email. Now, form is submitted but data is not added in Trigger DE and Trigger Email is also not sent.

```
if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_extkey = "12188314"
SET @ts_email = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
SET @ts_subkey = _subscriberkey

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", @ts_extkey)
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
 
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @ts_email)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

ENDIF
```

Added the HTML as below

```
<form action="https://pub.s10.exacttarget.com/2d0my0f2vky"  method="POST">
    
  <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress" required="required" name="EmailAddress" value="">

   <input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted" />
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: shouldn't this  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "Email", @Email_Address) be  SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @Email_Address)

Comment: "Email" it is the field name in DE.

Comment: Did you not use a DE based on the triggeredsend template?

Comment: I changed the logic using single page and only triggering the email. Now, form is submitted but data is not added in Trigger DE and Trigger Email is also not sent. Updated the Coded in my question.

Comment: Yes, Created the DE using Trigger Send Template

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the `<form action="" >`. I was sending the data to next page using the action tag but the trigger code is written on the same page. Removed the `action=""` tag.
It's working fine now.